# Add cocoapods to existing project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I know this have been asked multiple times, but I still couldn't find the right answer.

I have a project (React Native) that already has a lot of code, lots of dependencies, xcode tweaks, etc. Far away from a vanilla project.

I want to add cocoa pods to it because some third party library can only be installed with it. However, I can't find anywhere information about if I need to "migrate" all my third party packages as well to cocoa pods (move all the linked dependencies there), or is it enough to create a fresh pod file with just those two new dependencies, and everything else should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Install CocoaPods on System

Step.1 Open Terminal and enter the following command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Create Podfile for Project

Step.2 now you need to close Xcode.

Open Terminal at project's root folder

Step.3 Next, enter below command to create podfile:

```
pod init
```

Edit podfile

Note: Make sure we will edit podfile with Xcode not TextEdit etc.

Step.4 Type this command to open the Podfile using Xcode for editing:

```
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

Step.5 update pode file what you want.
for example

```
pod 'SwiftForms'
```

when you add this line it wii installing at next step :)

let's go for install

Step.5 Enter the following command in Terminal and hit Enter

```
pod install
```

Thats it!! we have done.

Open Project with pods

Now go to the project folder,we can see that CocoaPods created a new project_name.xcworkspace file and a Pods folder.

open project_name.xcworkspace with xcode

Comment: This is what I did, but it still doesn't answer my question. Do I need to manually add to the podfile all my existing third party libraries that were previously manually linked, or just the one that needs a podfile? I'm asking this because right now adding a podfile just breaks my whole project and it won't compile.

Comment: @CristianoCoelho yes you must all of your third party library must be in your new pod file. because it is creating new .xcworkspace file with your pod file. i wish it is helping you.

Comment: Is there a way to migrate an xcode project to pods then? This is just silly

Answer (score 0):

This article has the answer I needed in a very similar situation: https://medium.com/@soufianerafik/how-to-add-pods-to-an-xcode-project-2994aa2abbf1

Essentially this:

0. install Cocoapods, if needed
1. terminal to your project root
2. pod init
3. pod install